# Azure Identity Protection - Risk Detection API - Filter by date

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to filter the RiskDetection data retrieved from Azure Identity Protection by date and so far no success.

For the below sample data below filter by activityDateTime (or any date fields in the sample data) show internal error in the response:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/riskDetections?$filter=activityDateTime ge 2020-02-05

```
{'error': {'code': 'Internal Server Error', 'message': 'There was an internal 
server error while processing the request. 
Error ID: 0c2de841-9d83-479a-b7f2-ed2c102908f6', 
'innerError': 
{'request-id': '0c2de841-9d83-479a-b7f2-ed2c102908f6', 
'date': '2020-02-07T01:28:17'}}}
```

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters

> Note: The following $filter operators are not supported for Azure AD
>   resources: ne, gt, ge, lt, le, and not. The contains string operator
>   is currently not supported on any Microsoft Graph resources.

Is there a way to filter by date for RiskDetections? Will appreciate any help.

**Below filter with riskType and riskLevel shows data:**

risk_detections_api_url =  "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/riskDetections?$filter=riskType eq 'anonymizedIPAddress' or riskLevel eq 'medium'"

**Below filter with userPrincipalName shows data:**

risk_detections_api_url =  "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/riskDetections?$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'john.doe@example.com'"

**Below filter with ipAddress shows data:**

risk_detections_api_url =  "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/riskDetections?$filter=ipAddress eq '195.228.45.176'"

**Sample data**

```
{
        "id": "8901d1fee9bqwqweqwe683a221af3d2ae691736f2e369e0dd530625398",
        "requestId": "cc755f41-0313-4cb2-96ce-3a6283fef200",
        "correlationId": "c422083d-0e32-4afb-af4e-6ca46e4235b4",
        "riskType": "anonymizedIPAddress",
        "riskState": "atRisk",
        "riskLevel": "medium",
        "riskDetail": "none",
        "source": "IdentityProtection",
        "detectionTimingType": "realtime",
        "activity": "signin",
        "tokenIssuerType": "AzureAD",
        "ipAddress": "195.228.45.176",
        "activityDateTime": "2019-12-26T17:40:02.1402381Z",
        "detectedDateTime": "2019-12-26T17:40:02.1402381Z",
        "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2019-12-26T17:43:21.8931807Z",
        "userId": "e3835755-80b0-4b61-a1c0-5ea9ead75300",
        "userDisplayName": "John Doe",
        "userPrincipalName": "john.doe@example.com",
        "additionalInfo": "[{\"Key\":\"userAgent\",\"Value\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0\"}]",
        "location": {
            "city": "Budapest",
            "state": "Budapest",
            "countryOrRegion": "HU",
            "geoCoordinates": {
                "latitude": 47.45996,
                "longitude": 19.14968
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide the date in the UTC format.

Example:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/riskDetections?$filter=activityDateTime ge **2020-01-01T22:13:50.843847Z**

In python you would do something like below to create the URL with filter:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_filter = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()+"Z"
request_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/riskDetections?$filter=activityDateTime ge " + date_filter
```

The response is now filtered:

```
[
    {
        "id": "68f0402c7063a2fbbae5895f2c63598ca3c2b81c44be60145be1a9cd7e20af4b",
        "requestId": "181d3817-b4fb-4d2b-a87c-065776f05800",
        "correlationId": "6d02786c-0bc7-441f-b303-51430016f955",
        "riskType": "unfamiliarFeatures",
        "riskState": "atRisk",
        "riskLevel": "low",
        "riskDetail": "none",
        "source": "IdentityProtection",
        "detectionTimingType": "realtime",
        "activity": "signin",
        "tokenIssuerType": "AzureAD",
        "ipAddress": "52.185.138.50",
        "activityDateTime": "2020-02-07T05:48:07.6322964Z",
        "detectedDateTime": "2020-02-07T05:48:07.6322964Z",
        "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2020-02-07T05:49:33.3003616Z",
        "userId": "e3835755-80b0-4b61-a1c0-5ea9ead75300",
        "userDisplayName": "John Doe",
        "userPrincipalName": "john.doe@example.com",
        "additionalInfo": "[{\"Key\":\"userAgent\",\"Value\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36\"}]",
        "location": {
            "city": "tokyo",
            "state": "tokyo",
            "countryOrRegion": "jp",
            "geoCoordinates": {
                "latitude": 35.69628,
                "longitude": 139.7386
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/riskdetection?view=graph-rest-beta#properties), `activityDateTime` is `datetimeoffset` type.

So you should use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/riskDetections?$filter=activityDateTime gt 2019-12-25` rather than `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/riskDetections?$filter=activityDateTime gt '2019-12-25'`.

A similar API document here: [List directoryAudits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters).

But when I test it, it gives 500 error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Internal Server Error",
        "message": "There was an internal server error while processing the request. Error ID: d52436f6-073b-4fc8-b3bc-c6a6336d6886",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d52436f6-073b-4fc8-b3bc-c6a6336d6886",
            "date": "2020-02-05T04:10:45"
        }
    }
}
```

I believe beta version for this API is still in change. You could contact Microsoft support with your request-id for further investigation.